# Repligo RGO file

Tags: ebook-reader

Is there any app to open **Repligo .RGO** files?
It seems that [Cerience](http://www.cerience.com) doesn't support it anymore.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [Repligo Reader for Android](http://www.cerience.com/products/reader/android) available... If you want some alternatives you should take a look at [RepliGo Reader Alternatives for Android](http://alternativeto.net/software/repligo-reader/?platform=android)

Comment: Thank you but none of the mentioned apps support **.RGO** file type. They just open pdf files.

Comment: I would convert **.RGO** files to more portable ones like **PDF**, **Mobi** and **ePub**

Comment: What to do if there is thousands of them?

Comment: Bulk conversion tools maybe...

Comment: Do you know any?

Comment: http://www.pdfpdf.com/batch.html

Comment: Doesn't support **.RGO**, sorry!

Comment: No idea, sorry... **:(**

Answer (score -1):

i use "Autoit" make script and auto convert(print) to pdf.

Comment: What's AutoIt? Please provide a link, especially since not everybody is familiar with it. Do you also have the script that will convert it to PDF? Please improve your answer. :)